# gitpython get last commit with detached head

Tags: git, gitpython, git-detached-head

In a up-to-date repository we do the following:

```sh
git checkout HEAD~5
```

Then using GitPython, we can obtain the head commit, which is detached:

```py
import git

repo = git.Repo('.')
head = repo.head
head_commit = head.commit
print(head.is_detached)
> True
```

**Is there a way in GitPython to obtain the last commit in the branch?**

I'm thinking of something along the lines of:

```py
last = repo.active_branch.last_commit  # active_branch will throw an error when head is detached.
```

or

```py
last = head_commit
# I dont even know if talking about child commits makes sense in git.
while last.child is not None:
    last = last.child
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last commit in *any* branch is given by the commit hash ID stored in the *branch name*.

That's all—it really is that simple.  Git commits link only *backwards*, from child to parent.  So each branch name *must* store the hash ID of its *last* commit.

> In a up-to-date repository we do the following:
>
> ```
> git checkout HEAD~5
> ```

After doing this, you have, as you said in the title, a "detached HEAD".  This means you *are no longer on any branch*.  The question of "last commit" becomes kind of meaningless: `HEAD` points directly to a commit, and that commit is by definition the *current* commit.  You may check out any commit you like, e.g., by giving `git checkout` a raw commit hash ID, and you will continue to be on a detached HEAD, but on a different commit.

The effect is that you are now on an anonymous branch (one with no name) whose *last* commit is the *current* commit.  Creating a new branch at this point, pointing to this commit, causes that branch to come into existence.  Its last commit is the current commit, so now the last commit on the newly created branch is the current commit.

Given a chain of commits like:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- br1
                   \
                    J <-K   <-- br2
```

*all* the commits up through `I` are on `br2`, even though `I` is also the *last* commit of `br1` so that all the commits up through `I` are on `br1`.  They are on *both* branches.  Commits `J` and `K` are *only* on `br2`.

If we delete the *name* `br1`, all the commits continue to be findable via the name `br2`.  Git finds (all) commits by reading each hash ID from (all) branch names and other such names, then working backwards from those commits to their parents, and to the parents' parents, and so on.

If at this point you `git checkout br1` and create one new commit, you get:

```
                    L   <-- br1 (HEAD)
                   /
... <-F <-G <-H <-I
                   \
                    J <-K   <-- br2
```

Note that `HEAD` is now attached to branch `br1`.  Commit `L` is the last commit in this branch; commits through `I` are in both branches.

If you now detach `HEAD` and move it to commit `I` you get:

```
                    L   <-- br1
                   /
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- HEAD
                   \
                    J <-K   <-- br2
```

#### Exercises (do these in order)

1. I will give you two raw commit hash IDs, with the provision that the first commit's hash ID will be reachable by starting at the second commit and walking backwards, one step at a time along these backward-pointing arrows.  For instance, I might give you the hash ID of commit `F` and the hash ID of commit `K`.  How can you use this information to find commit `G`?  (Think about starting at commit `K` and following each arrow while keeping some sort of log of each commit visited.)
2. What's the *next* commit *after* commit `I`?  What other information do you need in order to find this next commit?  Remember that commit `I` is on both `br1` and `br2`.

Comment: I think I got it. Since the git history is a tree one commit has one parent but may have 0 to many children. But the children information is not stored, just the parents, the leaves of this tree (each branch) and some other intermediate pointers (like our detached HEAD). The answers to your questions would be:

1. By starting at `K` we can iteratively get the parent of the commit, push the hash in a stack and continue until we reach the hash of  `F`. Then the hash of `G` will be in the stack.
2. We need another commit which is in either of these two branches to do process of anwser (1.)

Comment: RIght. Note though that *merge* commits have two (or more) parents, which complicates things: you have to walk backwards along both parent linkages. (Merges change the data structure from a tree to a graph—a Directed Acyclic Graph in Git. For your particular case, you probably have no merge commits to worry about.)